# Bash script menu option Square bracket

Tags: bash

I have a base script to list out the menu's like below, using the case statement I am fetching the options, based the option selection my script to run and install the software.

```
#!/bin/bash

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
clear

echo "==========================="
echo "Please read the options are below "
echo "==========================="

options=("Option 1: Tomcat Installation" "Option 2: Java Installation" "Option 3: JDBC JAR Installation" "Option 4: Clone Repository" "Option 5: Reply" "Quit")

COLUMNS=12
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
        case $opt in
"Option 1: Tomcat Installation")
 "Option 5: Reply")

                echo "Reply"
                echo "================================================================"
                echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
                ;;

        "Quit")
                break
                ;;

        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY" ;;
        esac
done


===========================
Please read the options are below 
===========================
1) Option 1: JAVA Installation
2) Option 2: Tomcat Installation
3) Option 3: JDBC JAR Installation
4) Option 4: Clone Repository
5) Option 5: Reply
6) Quit
Please enter your choice:
```

Is there any way to put the square bracket for above menus like below

```
=====================================
Please read the options are below   =
=====================================
1) Option 1: JAVA Installation      =
2) Option 2: Tomcat Installation    =
3) Option 3: JDBC JAR Installation  =
4) Option 4: Clone Repository       =
5) Option 5: Reply                  =
6) Quit                             =
=====================================
Please enter your choice:
```

please advise me if its possible, thanks.

Comment: ? Output the text that you presented. `echo =====================================` `echo "Please read the options are below   ="` etc. It's unclear, what exactly are you having problem with?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Notice the `=` marks at the end of each line in addition. And OP: Please post your example `Bash` code.

Comment: Hi Kamil and Steph, sorry for the trouble, i have updated the post.

Comment: You cannot modify the output of the `select` command, but you could certainly write something yourself that would produce the desired output...but in that case, you would also need to write your own code for reading the response.

Comment: Hi Lar, Thanks for the response, i will do some poc for this.